# evalState in a monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

Given a `mtl` monad stack, e.g. `ExceptT String (WriterT String (State s a))`, how can I evaluate the inner state monad without needing to unwrap the outer monads?

```
have :: ExceptT String (WriterT String (State s)) a
f    :: State s a -> a

want :: ExceptT String (WriterT String Identity) a
```

I can do this by calling `runExceptT` followed by `runWriterT` and repacking the results afterward but it seems like the wrong way to accomplish this.

---

As far as I tried, something like `fmap` or similar won't work because the monad transformer stack is treated as an entire monad on it's own. What I need is a functionality to "split" the monad transformer stack like this:

```
split :: (MonadTrans s, Monad t) => (s t) a -> s (t a)
```

Either I haven't found this function or the solution works entirely differently.

Comment: You can't. All a transformer adds is `lift :: m a -> t m a`. There's no generic way to implement what you're trying to do given just `Monad` and `MonadTrans` (the whole notion of "running" things isn't even part of the monad transformer concept). You can have specialized functions like in the answer, but no generic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach that seems simplest in this particular case is to use the `MFunctor` instances of the `ExceptT e` and `WriterT w` transformers:

```
import Control.Monad.Morph

floop :: Monad m
      => s
      -> ExceptT e (WriterT w (StateT s m)) a
      -> ExceptT e (WriterT w m) a
floop s = hoist (hoist $ flip evalStateT s)
```

Since `State s = StateT s Identity`, the slight generalization above is immediate.

Comment: `hoist` was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of anything as general as your `split`, but using the `map...T` functions could prevent the explicit manipulation:

```
have :: ExceptT String (WriterT String (State s)) a
f    :: State s a -> a

want :: ExceptT String (WriterT String Identity) a
want = mapExceptT (mapWriterT (return . f)) have
```